# Uneven horizontally scrolling div with white-space: normal

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a horizontally scrolling div with various other divs inside of it.

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="info">
            <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="info">
            <h1>This is a really long title</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="info">
            <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.slider {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: grey;
}

.info {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: normal;    
}
```

The problem I have is that each div has a title, and when it has `white-space: normal` set and the title is multiple lines, it throws off the alignment of the other divs.

Here is an example of the problem in action: http://jsfiddle.net/ur16gj3m/

Is there a way to get around this? If I change `.info` to `position: absolute`, it works. I'd prefer to not use absolute positioning though.

Comment: Use `overflow-x:auto` with `white-space:nowrap`

Comment: Did you check the example? I am using `white-space: nowrap` on the parent div, along with `overflow: auto`. I'm not having a problem with the actual scrolling part. I'm having a problem with the vertical alignment of the children divs inside the scroller.

Comment: [`vertical-align: top` is what you need](http://jsfiddle.net/4ujhpwk8/)

Comment: Thanks, that was basic haha. Didn't think of that. Wasn't sure why the children of one container was affecting the alignment of its siblings like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the default `vertical-align: baseline` property on inline elements. This causes the blocks to line themselves up with the baseline of the text. This is a problem when the text wraps as the baseline is pushed down.

Set `vertical-align: top` on `.item`

### Working Example

```css
.slider {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: grey;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.info {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="info">
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="info">
      <h1>This is a really long title</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="info">
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @LucasRaines - No worries :) look out for it in the future as this is quite a common reason for alignment issues using inline elements.